# What is the lowest wattage that can be used to charge a USB 3 Cellphone?

Tags: power, usb-device

So obviously there are various protocols to *increase* the charging speed of USB 3.0, but I would like to *decrease* it.

Basically I'm working a tiny generator which can only put out about 500mW. Is it possible to charge a cellphone directly using such a small amount of power?

Ideally if the power draw is too great for my generator, the voltage will sag and the phone will just accept whatever power it can get at some intermediate voltage like 4v. But of course it might do the opposite, and draw more current in an attempt to get the same power.

If USB 3.0 can't handle small amounts of power gracefully. What's the smallest amount of power that it *will* handle?

One solution I'm aware of is to store power in some intermediary like a super-cap or lipo, but if I can I would like to use the power directly, as that's more efficient.

Comment: The answer is: **it depends**. Not all phones respond the same. Some simply **stop charging** if they cannot get enough power. Others **charge slowly**. This has no direct relation to USB 3.0. The USB 3.0 standard is backwards compatible with USB 2.0 and 1.0 which allow for peripherals like a mouse that draws only a small amount of current. If a phone can do the same (draw a small amount and current to charge the battery with that) is up to the phone's design.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a 100% solution, I would like to give some information that would be useful anyway. Maybe you'll solve your problem with it.

First of all, when the phone is turned on and not in standby mode, it uses some 4V (battery voltage) @ 250-1250ma depending on what it does, typically around 400-500ma. I can speak for iphones more confidently, I work in repair thing, power consumption is something I look at a lot). When the device is idle (lock screen, display off), it usually uses a few milliamps to zero, actually impressive. So you can only charge the phone as long as it's off or not in use. Second of all, it's hard to predict what happens if you limit the provided current. How do you want to limit it? If your charger output voltage drops to limit the current like lab bench power supplies do, you will probably end up with undervoltet output and the internal circuitry may stop accepting it as a valid charger. Alternatively, some charging circuits will accept even 4.4V input instead of 5. You will have to experiment to see if it works, and there's no guarantee it will work for everything. Tbh you'll have to try stuff, as I see it. Don't worry, you won't burn your phone or anything else. There is no way to break something from a short term undervolt even if it happens, it will just stop charging, no harm. If you keep experimenting with it and get some results, post them here, please. Would be interesting to see.

Comment: Is it really true you can't damage a phone, supplying a lower voltage / undervolting? I used to charge my THL off solar, and the phone started enjoying shorting the battery out further down the line. I never knew if it was my doing or just the age of the device.

Comment: short-term experiment (several times/several days) definitely can't damage anything. Most devices have unvervoltage protection (chips discuss in datasheets how they handle them - for example by disconnecting load and stopping charging). If you ever damage something with undervolt like that, it must be some unprotected VERY cheap charging circuit (the one you design on a lap in 30 minutes) and long exposure (weeks/months of regular undervolted charging). Of course, I can't promise it for every device/phone in the world. Did you make sure you had stable voltage without large ripple?